# Setting a Stripe Subscription with a Customer without a Default PaymentMethod in Java

Tags: stripe-payments

**This question is a misunderstanding on how to collect a PaymentMethod for a subscription, with the new SCA requirements. The key, was to read carefully how to [Sep up a Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/set-up-subscription0025), which is slightly different than with single payments.**

I'm migrating a Stripe implementation to the version 16.4.0, for an app developed with Java using the Spring-boot framework, in order to support the Strong Customer Authentication (SCA) requirements.

The problem is that **I can't create a subscription, because the customer doesn't have any Payment Method**.

That's my workflow for a subscription:

I create a customer:

```
   Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
   params.put("name", customerName);
   params.put("email", user.getUsername());
   params.put("description", "idweb: " + user.getIdweb() + " " + customerName);
   Customer customer = Customer.create(params);
   customerId = customer.getId();
```

Next, I create a subscription for this customer:

```
   Map<String, Object> firstItem = new HashMap<>();
   firstItem.put("plan", baseFee);
   firstItem.put("quantity", 1);

   Map<String, Object> secondItem = new HashMap<>();
   secondItem.put("plan", perUnitFee);
   secondItem.put("quantity", propertiesBase);

   Map<String, Object> items = new HashMap<>();
   items.put("0", firstItem);
   items.put("1", secondItem);

   Map<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();
   metadata.put("properties", properties);
   metadata.put("RwRate", stripePlans.getRwRate());

   Map<String, Object> subscriptionParams = new HashMap<>();
   subscriptionParams.put("customer", customerId);
   subscriptionParams.put("collection_method", "charge_automatically");
   subscriptionParams.put("items", items);
   subscriptionParams.put("metadata", metadata);

   Subscription subscription = Subscription.create(subscriptionParams);
```

Here the system raises this error:

```
com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method.
```

As I have understood from the documentation *...using an API version on or after 2019-03-14*, the system sets a subscription into the status *incomplete*, if a payment intent fails, so that we can collect the payment method at the front end.

If I could create the subscription, I would take its latest invoice from which I would take its Payment Intent to pass the *Client Secret* to the front end.

```
    Invoice invoice = Invoice.retrieve(subscription.getLatestInvoice());
    PaymentIntent paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.retrieve(invoice.getPaymentIntent());
    model.addAttribute("clientSecret", paymentIntent.getClientSecret());
```

From this point onwards, I should be able to assign the collected payment method to the guest and leave the subscription active, for the next payments, as it has been working until now without the SCA requirements.

**I may be missing something or my approach may be wrong, in any case any advice would be more than welcome**. I've read about different approaches, setting a trial period or setting a *SetupIntent*. But my ideal scenario, is to charge the first quota when collecting the customer's card and leaving the subscription ready, for the next ones to be automatically charged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Sources, you need to set the Customer's `default_source`.

If you're instead using the newer PaymentMethods API (and you should unless you have a good reason not to), you'll want to instead set the Customer's `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`.

There's details in [the Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#signup-3) for more on this.

Comment: I'm moving to the PaymentMethods API and my problem setting the subscription after having collected the PaymentMethod at the front end (JS: stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret,...), is that the subscription creates the first invoice and a second charge. I've read, that with a trial period it can be solved, but I'm wondering whether is possible to set the subscription and leaving it incomplete, before collecting the PaymentMethod at the front end.

Comment: If you already have the PaymentMethod, you can pass it as the Subscription's `default_payment_method` as another option when creating the Subscription.

Comment: I'm missing something. 

When the customer enters the card details I want to charge the first quota of its subscription, dealing with the SCA and at the same time, to confirm the subscription without getting a second charge for the first invoice. For what I read, I understood that it was possible, without setting a trial period (preventing the double charge), but maybe it's not.

Comment: This question was a misunderstanding on how to collect a PaymentMethod for a subscription, with the new SCA requirements. The key, was to read carefully how to [Sep up a Subscription][1], which is slightly different than with single payments.